# Are there any implementations of HTTP(s) stack independent from Internet Explorer engine?

Tags: c#, networking

I'm writing the code which unfortunately needs to be run on Windows XP, sometimes.

The code makes requests to HTTPS, where security protocol is not supported by IE on Windows XP. Hence the question: are there any independent implementations of WebClient, where it doesn't use any of host system API, but rather implements all networking/authentication/etc. by itself?

My question is so strange that even Google fails to provide me with meaningful results. Hopefully you could suggest anything.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you talking about the lack of TLS 1.1/1.2 support? Thats an operating system limitation rather than something specific to IE.  There are libcurl bindings for .Net - libcurl.net  (I would be surprised if this did not have TLS support but I've never used it)

Comment: As even Google Chrome does not do that, you can calculate if you want to move on.

Comment: Mozilla Firefox does that. Where IE 8 fails to open certain websites, Firefox opens them.